# Pinging a Minecraft Server in PHP: Small Error

Tags: php, html, minecraft

I'm trying to input data from a Minecraft server into my webpage, as a test. Here is the code:

```
<?php $host = "hub.cobalt-mc.com";
$port = 25565;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$connected = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
if ($connected) {
$ping_start = microtime(true);
socket_send($socket, "\xFE", 1, 0);
$data = "";
$result = socket_recv($socket, &$data, 1024, 0);$ping_end = microtime(true);
socket_close($socket);

if ($result != false && substr($data, 0, 1) == "\xFF") {
$info = explode("\xA7", mb_convert_encoding(substr($data,1), "iso-8859-1","utf-16be"));
$serverName = substr($info[0], 1);
$playersOnline = $info[1];
$playersMax = $info[2];
$ping = round(($ping_end - $ping_start) * 1000);
echo     "<table class=\"table table-hover\">
<th>Server Address</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Total DP</th>

<tr>
<td>$host:$ip</td>
if (($ping > '1000') || ($ping < '0')) {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
else {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>$host:$ip</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>";
                            }

 else {
 echo "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Error: </span>Failed to receive data";
 }
 } else {
 echo "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Error: </span>Failed to send data";
 }?>
```

I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/mctronco/public_html/leaderboards/serverping.php on line 27
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: I understand that you are new to this, but if you want people to debug for you, you'll get more help if you line up your code properly... While you're at it, you'll probably find the error.

Comment: You are trying to add more PHP code in the middle of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echo that starts right after the `$ping = round(...` line is not terminated before the if statement ... you can't just drop an `if` in the middle of an `echo`

The line that reads:

```
<td>$host:$ip</td>
```

Should be:

```
<td>$host:$ip</td>";
```

Then you need to do another echo after the if statement ...

There seem to be a myriad of other issues in that code that will prevent you from doing what you want ...

As stated in the comments, proper code formatting will go a long way toward solving these errors ... use an editor that colorizes code and errors like this will jump out at you ...

Comment: Thank you. I'm still beginning PHP so I'm not the best. Sometimes looking over the code does help.

Comment: @JakeGould: I prefer the syntax the way you have it, but since the entire echo string is in double quotes, the variable replacements will work ...

Answer (score 0):

Your error message refers to line 27:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/mctronco/public_html/leaderboards/serverping.php on line 27
```

So it’s not clear what specific line has an issue.  So I would recommend you change all of as follows since your coding is quite munged. This is not my ideal, but should work.

```
if ($result != false && substr($data, 0, 1) == "\xFF") {
$info = explode("\xA7", mb_convert_encoding(substr($data,1), "iso-8859-1","utf-16be"));
$serverName = substr($info[0], 1);
$playersOnline = $info[1];
$playersMax = $info[2];
$ping = round(($ping_end - $ping_start) * 1000);

echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">";
echo "<th>Server Address</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>Rank</th>";
echo "<th>Total DP</th>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$host:$ip</td>";
if (($ping > '1000') || ($ping < '0')) {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
else {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$host.":".$ip."</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
                            }

 else {
 echo "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Error: </span>Failed to receive data";
 }
 } else {
 echo "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Error: </span>Failed to send data";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code but I am going to point out an important issue.  You cannot put pure PHP in the middle of a string or echo.

OLD CODE

```
<tr>
<td>$host:$ip</td>
if (($ping > '1000') || ($ping < '0')) {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
else {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
<td></td>
```

NEW CODE

```
<tr>
<td>{$host}:{$ip}</td>";

if (($ping > '1000') || ($ping < '0')) {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}
else {
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-success\">Online!</span></td>";
}

echo "
<td></td>
```

It would be better if you did the if statement outside of the echo storing its result in a variable and then putting the variable inside the echo.  While you are inside double quotes (like your echo) you can have PHP show the contents of a variable but it won't execute statements.